# How do I set session timeout in JBoss-6.4_EAP

Tags: jboss6.x

I am using JBoss EAP 6 and would like to know how to configure the session-timeout property. Unlike jboss-4.0.5.GA, there is no web.xml in folder /deployers/jbossweb.deployer/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default session timeout by changing the `default-session-timeout` attribute of the web subsystem.

Setting it 15 minutes for example:

`/subsystem=web:write-attribute(name=default-session-timeout,value=15)`

result in xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false" default-session-timeout="15">
        </subsystem>
```